# Being charged with driving while impaired, in the state of Minnesota? While prescribed desoxyn

Tags: criminal-law, driving, statutes, minnesota

Or while being prescribed desoxyn by a doctor,  Is there a limit of methamphetamine in one's system that can allow  one to drive and not be charged with driving while impaired, in the state of Minnesota?  Kind of like .08 for alcohol. And or if it is not impairing judgment .

Comment: Could [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "meth" please?  Methylated spirits?  Methamphetamine?  At the same time, it would be good to expand the abbreviations dui and mn - not everyone here is US based - and to fix "one" to "ones" and "on" to "one".  Also, what does this have to do with the us-constitution? I would remove that tag.

Comment: @MartinBonner: In the US, "meth" is a standard  shorthand for "methamphetamine".  I have never heard it used to mean anything else.  I have edited the question.

Comment: OP: “Kind of like 0.08” for alcohol is not completely correct anyway. See the link in the (excellent) answer by @Nate Eldredge. For alcohol it is under the influence of alcohol (1) or having 0.08 (5). So 0.08 and you seem “fine” is still a crime. Driving erratically and 0.06 is also a crime. It is just that 0.08 itself is a crime. Lower than that and they need other evidence of being impaired (like field sobriety test).

Comment: How can they say you are impaired even if it has been 5 days since last use or more and levels are 10,000ppm?

Comment: In a legal context, "impaired" means whatever the law says it means, regardless of whether or not you are "impaired" in the common sense of the word.  (By the way, if your blood level of methamphetamine is 10,000ppm you will be dead: 10 ppm is considered lethal.  Being dead will certainly impair your ability to drive.)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you mean methamphetamine, then the answer is **no**.  It is illegal to drive with any amount of methamphetamine in one's body.

The main Minnesota law on driving while impaired (DWI) is [Section 169A.20 subdivision 1](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/169A.20):

> It is a crime for any person to drive, operate, or be in physical
> control of any motor vehicle, as defined in section 169A.03,
> subdivision 15, except for motorboats in operation and off-road
> recreational vehicles, within this state or on any boundary water of
> this state when:
> [...]
>
> (7) the person's body contains **any amount of a controlled substance
> listed in Schedule I or II**, or its metabolite, other than marijuana or
> tetrahydrocannabinols.

The schedules of controlled substances are at [Section 152.02](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/152.02).  Methamphetamine is listed in Schedule II (subd. 3 (d) (3)).

**However**, there is an exception if you were taking the substance as a prescription.  [Section 169A.49 subd. 2](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/169A.46):

> If proven by a preponderance of the evidence, it is an affirmative defense to a violation of section 169A.20, subdivision 1, clause (7) (presence of Schedule I or II controlled substance), that the defendant used the controlled substance according to the terms of a prescription issued for the defendant in accordance with sections 152.11 and 152.12.

Note that since this is an affirmative defense, the burden of proof falls on *you* to prove that you had a prescription, and that you were using the substance according to its terms (e.g. taking only the prescribed dose).  In particular, if your doctor or pharmacist told you not to drive while taking it, then that would seem to say that you were *not* using the substance as prescribed.

Comment: Before the edit with the affirmative defense, I was a little surprised it was just a blanket rule. CII amphetamines are commonly prescribed meds for attention deficit disorder. I'd rather those with ADD/ADHD be medicated while driving, both for improved attention control, but also for curbing the impulsiveness.

Comment: Is there any loop hole on them statues  being charged with 4° DUI and getting test refusal and not having a sample then charged with 3°DUI aggravated  and having a sample for methamphetamine. But never been convicted of the 4 degree yet.?

Comment: @jail: I don't know.  If this is a real-life situation then you need to ask your lawyer instead of relying on random people from the Internet (I am definitely not a lawyer).